# changing window.location without triggering refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an AJAX form that submits GET requests. Because these are all GET requests these should be easily bookmark-able. Preferably I'd make my Ajax request, update the screen and then update window.location.href to be the URL for the new page.

Unfortunately this reloads the page. Is there any way I can get around this? Basically I'd like the URL bar to be a permalink bar, but it needs to be able to change to keep up with the state of the page.

window.location.hash is no good because that doesn't get sent to the server.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
window.history.replaceState( {} , title, new_URL );
```

This will update the current page URL with a new one **without refreshing**.

### Arguments:

1. Data object (must be one that could be serialized to text)
2. The new title of the changed window URL
3. The URL to change to (without refreshing)

The you could use the `window.onpopstate = function(event){...}` to listen to events when a user goes back or forward in the browser history and change things however you wish.

Answer (score 6):

The hash is the way to go. Because, as you point out, changes to the hash don't get sent to the server, you have to send an async request to the server as well as updating the hash.

As a simple example, if your URL is `http://server.com/page?id=4`, when the user triggers the action you send an AJAX request for `http://server.com/page?id=4`, and set the page URL to `http://server.com/page#id=4`.

Furthermore, you have to have something to restore the state if the user reloads. This would usually be done by reading the hash value client-side and sending an async request to the server based on the state represented by the hash value.

Comment: Well, it makes me sad but I guess there's no way around this. Am I crazy or does it seem like I should be able to say "Hey browser, I updated the page and I'd like you to reflect that. And next time you come here, how about I just serve you that new resource." and the browser says "Let's not. How about you serve me a page that I will then process so that you it makes a second request to get the page you wanted in the first place." "Allright man, it's your world."

Comment: I think HTML5's History feature may provide this, but it will be a long time before it's commonly available.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#history

Comment: awesome. looks like window.history.replaceState is what I want. that and a browser that implements it :(

Comment: `window.location.hash` is the part of URL after hash sign '#', which is not sent to the server (it is used by the client to scroll to the anchor indicated by part after the hash sign), thus changing it does not trigger page reload. However, it does not help with changing any other parts of the URL (e.g. anything before '#' cannot be affected). So it is useless.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to do which works in current browser, you can't change `window.location.href` without reloading the page

your only option is to to change `window.location.hash`.

you can do that each time you make an ajax call. if you're using jquery, you can bind a function which update the hash each time an ajax call is made.
if you choose that you'll have to look for the hash on page load (actually don't know/think you can do that server side) and make that call to have your page on the state corresponding to the hash.

-- update

there is now an API which provide this functionality look for history.pushState, history.replaceState and window.onpopstate : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

it's not availlable everywhere yet ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=history ), there is a few polyfill that you can use for the moment that will use this API if it's available and fall back using the url hash

Comment: `window.location.hash` is the part of URL after hash sign '#', which is not sent to the server (it is used by the client to scroll to the anchor indicated by part after the hash sign), thus changing it does not trigger page reload. However, it does not help with changing any other parts of the URL (e.g. anything before '#' cannot be affected). So it is useless.

window.history.replaceState( is the way to go.

Comment: @iva2k and that’s exactly what is written (in poor English). The first par of this answers is from 2010 and don’t mention replaceState because it was nonexistent or barely. The second part (from 2013) mentions it because it became a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this JavaScript library: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: Be ware that history.js is no longer maintained

Answer (score -7):

Use jquery. It can do ajax requests. You cant use window.location because that is made to change the url.